# downgrading the angular version 11-9

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules

```
 {
  "name": "lms-ace-learn",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/localize": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.9",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^1.2.3",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^20.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/moment-duration-format": "^2.2.2",
    "angular-ng-autocomplete": "^2.0.1",
    "angularx-social-login": "^3.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "moment-duration-format": "^2.3.2",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^6.1.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.4.2",
    "ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.1.0",
    "ngx-captcha": "^8.0.1",
    "ngx-chips": "^2.1.0",
    "ngx-doc-viewer": "^1.3.1",
    "ngx-drag-drop": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^9.1.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-sortablejs": "^3.1.4",
    "ngx-spinner": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^13.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "sortablejs": "^1.12.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.17.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.6",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/sortablejs": "^1.10.6",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

[Core package error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2xEB.png)

My system had Angular 11. When i am trying the downgrading the Angular Version to 9 for this project; after the successfully downgrade into Angular 9 and reinstall the node_modules, these errors are popped up and these errors are core package errors.
What should i do??

Comment: How did you downgraded to lower version? Did you manually changed the version of each package?

Comment: No @VimalPatel i was used these 3 commands npm uninstall -g @angular/cli | npm cache clean | npm install -g @angular/cli@9.1.13

Comment: That's for global angular cli, I am asking for project downgrade process?

Comment: No i did this for local also

Comment: try updating  @angular/cdk": "9.2.3"  version as well

Comment: still getting the same error @LogicBlower

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  "name": "lms-ace-learn",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/localize": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.9",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^1.2.3",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^20.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^5.0.1",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-richtexteditor": "^18.4.42",
    "@types/moment-duration-format": "^2.2.2",
    "angular-ng-autocomplete": "^2.0.1",
    "angularx-social-login": "^3.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "moment-duration-format": "^2.3.2",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^6.1.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.4.2",
    "ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.1.0",
    "ngx-captcha": "^8.0.1",
    "ngx-chips": "^2.1.0",
    "ngx-doc-viewer": "^1.3.1",
    "ngx-drag-drop": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^9.1.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-sortablejs": "^3.1.4",
    "ngx-spinner": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^13.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "sortablejs": "^1.12.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.17.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.6",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/sortablejs": "^1.10.6",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

After changing all the version's of CLI according to the project it's works fine without any bugs. Thank you guys for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You should downgrade this package too:

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.1",
```

Use "~0.901.14" version instead.

Comment: You can try to create new project using angular 9 cli, and then copy correct dependencies from this new project to your old one

Comment: Thanks @Aracturat allredy fixed the bug